# Search Multidimensional Array ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, search, loops, multidimensional-array

If I have two arrays like the example below, how can I search the first part of each node in the 'score' array with the values in the 'search' array and return the value that is the second part of each node in the 'score' array? Basically in this case I'd want to get 5 and 7.

```
var score:Array = new Array(); 
score[0] = ["cat", "3"];
score[1] = ["dog", "5"];
score[2] = ["fish", "0.5"];
score[3] = ["bird", "0.25"];
score[4] = ["horse", "10"];
score[5] = ["cow", "15"];
score[6] = ["iguana", "7"];

var search:Array = ["dog", "iguana"];
```

Comment: Can you just flatten the array `score["dog"] = 5;`? It'd inherently simplify the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code (using Dictionary):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private var score:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
            private var search:Array = ["dog", "iguana"];

            public function init():void{
                score["cat"] = "3";
                score["dog"] = "5";
                score["fish"] = "0.5";
                score["bird"] = "0.25";
                score["horse"] = "10";
                score["cow"] = "15";
                score["iguana"] = "7";

                var t1:String = score[search[1]];
                var t2:String = score[search[0]];
                Alert.show(t1 + ' ' + t2); //prints 5 7
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Or you can do this too:

```
            var t1:String = score["dog"];
            var t2:String = score["iguana"];
```

Or without Dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        public function init():void{
            score[0] = ["cat","3"];
            score[1] = ["dog","5"];
            score[2] = ["fish","0.5"];
            score[3] = ["bird","0.25"];
            score[4] = ["horse","10"];
            score[5] = ["cow","15"];
            score[6] = ["iguana","7"];

            for(var j:int = 0;j<search.length;j++){
                for(var i:int = 0;i<score.length;i++){
                    var temp:Array = score[i] as Array;
                    if(temp[0] == search[j]){
                        Alert.show(temp[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Also you have not used an appropriate way to declare arrays, I recommend using my method or changing the array declaration.